# List files in shell script and pass it as a argument to python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a shell script test.sh and a python script test.py
In the shell script test.sh, I need to list all the .py files in a directory and then pass it as a argument to the python script. The test.py should take that argument and download the python files.

```
def download():
   logic to download all the .py files
def parseval():
   parser = Optionparser()
   ...(all the code to parse the arguments
def main():
   opts, args = parseval()
   download(args)
```

Can anyone help me how to do it combining both shell script and python script?

Comment: The first question that other will ask is `Then what work will you do` don't plainly ask question `give some code that you have tried` some sample input and expected output

Comment: Not without seeing your shell script, no.

Comment: By the way you can get input to python script using sys.argv[] give a list as input it will be taken as string in the python program then convert it into list again then give it to `download()`

Comment: or you can give the input space separated and loop through sys.argv[] to get the input but i don't know how to use `shell` so that part is fully up to you

Comment: Also, did you know that python could also list the contents of a directory or only a specific set of files (e.g. those ending in ".py")? Check out the `glob` module and `os.listdir`.

Comment: @OliverW. that solved the problem :) as per my view